# I want to build a Chrome extension which automate Ctrl+f with word fed/stored in the tool for all websites I visit

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a requirement to highlight some particular words on any websites I visit. So that I don't have to use control+f manually and find the word on a web page.

I have seen some chrome plugin (Highlight This: finds and marks words
) but that is not finding on all websites maybe only for the website which allows **scraping**. I have some internal websites where I need to do ctrl+f every time for the same set of words.

Exactly this plugin is as per my requirement but this does not work internal or restricted websites. I know how to create extension but not sure what logic or piece of code would do this work.

When ever I visit a website or any URL the words stored in the plugin should highlight as it gets highlited with ctrl+f.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. Not fully tested.

```
  let searchTerms = ['law', 'software', 'news', 'health'];

  let elems = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a")
  for (let i = 0, total = elems.length; i < total; i++) {
    let element = elems[i];
    if (element && element.innerText) {
      let innerText = element.innerText;
      for (let j = 0; j < searchTerms.length; j++) {
        const reg = new RegExp(searchTerms[j], 'gi')
        const matches = innerText.toLowerCase().match(reg) || []
        if (matches.length) {
          for (let n = 0; n < matches.length; n++) {
            element.innerHTML = innerText.replace(reg, '<span style="color:red">' + searchTerms[j] + '</span>');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the chrome.storage.sync.set API  [chrome.storage.api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage).  You could set your text that searched and store it in a variable, then everytime you use the extension, you can have it reference that variable.  Without any code, I'm going off of my own experience.  So I'm including a bit of my example to show you how I used the chrome.storage api, so that maybe you could find it useful as well.

Here's a snippet of my code, it is a chrome extension that adds a url to the local storage so that way when I log into a firewall, I don't have to continually copy the string/text I'm wanting to input.

```
function cfs_add(){
var url = prompt('Please provide url', 'test.com');
chrome.storage.sync.set({'name': url}, function() {
  console.log("saved url!!" );
});
};
cfs_add()

...

chrome.storage.sync.get(['name'], function(results) {
  if(results.variable_name == undefined) {
  }
  document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = "Current URL: " + String(results['name'])
  document.getElementById('state').style.color = "lightblue"
```

})

Make a function that automatically searches and highlights the word stored in the local storage/chrome.storage.